# How to perform inner sort of an List<> in object?

Tags: c#, sorting, automation, compare

I am trying to wrap my head around this, but can't think of any good way to do it. I have an object, for which the properties are one certain class (Though could contain multiple Classes, Lists etc.). These might be null or empty. An example of the structure can be seen below. So here I would have some string data, objects, List and even in the List a list object.

**The goal is to get matched results from actual and Expected**

```
{
   "Name":"First Name",
   "LastName":"Yeah",
   "FavourityBooks":[
      {
         "BookName":"Hamlet",
         "Printed":"Outside USA",
         "PriceInDollars":100
      },
      {
         "BookName": "Romeo And the Girl",
         "Printed":"Somewhere In USA",
         "PriceInDollars":99
      }
   ],
   "Debt":[
      {
         "c":[
            {
               "FriendName":"August",
               "Amount":47
            },
            {
               "FriendName":"April",
               "Amount":53
            }
         ],
         "Sum":100
      },
      {
         "ToBanks":[
            {
               "BankName":"Scotland BAnk",
               "Amount":150
            },
            {
               "BankName":"Some Other Bank",
               "Amount":150
            }
         ],
         "Sum":300
      }
   ]
}
```

**One Way to go Sort Easily the Object by all properties**

These results are coming from Graph Ql, but development has not implemented a sorting method as far as I was told.

1. How could I sort The inner list of `FavourityBooks`, by all three properties?
2. How could I sort The inner list of `ToBanks` or `ToBanks` and sort the list which they are in as well?

I don't know if I can achieve this by hardcoding each of the list sorting separately. some kind of recursive function should be used in order to sort each child object by all of its properties.

This though seems a very complex task to me. Any ideas?

**Second Way to go is on the comparison level, more preferable**

The way how I was thinking to do is maybe can sort these objects on the comparison, not prior, though I am lacking the ideas, how to sort them in this area as well.

E.g. A method:

```
  public static List<EqualObjects> CompareObjects(object baseObject, object compareObject, object baseParentObject, object secondParentObject)
        {
            object basePropertyValue = null;
            object secondPropertyValue = null;
            var result = new List<EqualObjects>();
            var baseObjectType = baseObject.GetType();
            var secondObjectType = compareObject.GetType();

            var baseObjectProperties = baseObjectType.GetProperties();
            var secondObjectProperties = secondObjectType.GetProperties();

            foreach (var baseProperty in baseObjectProperties)
            {
                var compareProperty = secondObjectProperties.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == baseProperty.Name);
                //This gets the Object typeof(baseProperty) with the values
                secondPropertyValue = compareProperty.GetValue(compareObject, null); 
                basePropertyValue = baseProperty.GetValue(baseObject, null);

                var test = baseProperty.GetType().ToString();

                if (basePropertyValue is null)
                    continue;

                if (!baseProperty.PropertyType.FullName.Contains("System"))
                {
                    result.AddRange(CompareObjects(basePropertyValue, secondPropertyValue, baseObject, compareObject));
                    continue;
                }

                if (baseProperty.PropertyType.FullName == "System.String")
                {
                    result.AddRange(CompareSimpleElement(basePropertyValue, secondPropertyValue, baseObject, compareObject, baseProperty));
                    continue;
                }

                if (baseProperty.PropertyType.FullName == "System.Int32")
                {
                    result.AddRange(CompareSimpleElement(basePropertyValue, secondPropertyValue, baseObject, compareObject, baseProperty));
                    continue;
                }

                if (baseProperty.PropertyType.FullName == "System.Decimal")
                {
                    result.AddRange(CompareSimpleElement(basePropertyValue, secondPropertyValue, baseObject, compareObject, baseProperty));
                    continue;
                }

                //System.Collections.Generic.List

                if (baseProperty.PropertyType.FullName.Contains("System.Collections.Generic.List") && baseProperty.PropertyType.FullName.Contains("System.String"))
                {
                    var baseCollection = (List<string>)basePropertyValue;
                    var compareCollection = (List<string>)secondPropertyValue;
                    for (var i = 0; i < baseCollection.Count; i++)
                    {
                        if (baseCollection[i].Length > 0 && compareCollection[i].Length > 0)
                        {
                            result.AddRange(CompareSimpleList(baseCollection[i], compareCollection[i], baseObject,
                                compareObject, baseProperty,i));
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (baseProperty.PropertyType.FullName.Contains("System.Collections.Generic.List"))
                {
                    var baseCollection = (List<object>)basePropertyValue;
                    var compareCollection = (List<object>)secondPropertyValue;
                    for (var i = 0; i < baseCollection.Count; i++)
                    {
                     
                    }
                }

            }

            return result;
        }
```

Ideally, I could achieve this if I would be able to sort the `BaseCollection` and `compareCollection` by all properties (so if List, then sort by Object Properties) at first, then loop through and if another complex object would again sort it till it is a List which would always be the case once it gets here, other parts would be caught out previously.

```
  if (baseProperty.PropertyType.FullName.Contains("System.Collections.Generic.List"))
                {
                    var baseCollection = (List<object>)basePropertyValue;
                    var compareCollection = (List<object>)secondPropertyValue;
                    for (var i = 0; i < baseCollection.Count; i++)
                    {
                     
                    }
                }
```

Regards,

Comment: Have you looked at Linq? The Orderby and Group methods might work for you
Sorting https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/sorting-data
Grouping
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/grouping-data

Comment: OrderBy I can use, if I know the properties name, for this I would need to write for each class a separate method, array, etc. This is not a suitable answer as it would bring more complexity. Theoretically I am already failing here `var baseCollection = (List<object>)basePropertyValue; ` as I don't know how to cast The Object to List type object. I would need to do this for a General class, which I don't know upfront. 

Grouping would go in order by as well. On top of that I would need to extract the Object from object etc... Looking for an smoother solution :)

Comment: How little do you know about the structure the data will be in? like is there a set of structures it might be?

Comment: Why not just implementing the comparer for each object and call it a day ?

Comment: There are around 100 objects in different permutations so, call it a month/year, not a day :). The object will always be as specified e.g. `OutPutData`{}, though with time it will change, e.g. grow, adding more objects to it etc.

Comment: Trying to look something like:

`        static void DoSorting<T>(List<T> list1, List<T> list2)
        {
            foreach (var prop in list1)
            {
                list1 = list1.OrderBy(x=>x[prop.Something])
            }
        }`